# Is my Schrader valve spoilt?

Tags: tire, pump, schrader

(Tried searching this forum for this question but I couldn't find a question of the same type)

Hello, I've been trying to pump my front tyre but to no avail. I could easily pump the back tyre but not the front.

[image: Front valve]

[image: Grainy picture of back valve but what's clear to me was that the valve was "extended"(I could see a longer section)]

Picture of the front valve at the top,
The second picture is a grainy picture of back valve but what's clear to me was that the valve was "extended"(I could see a longer section)
Thanks!

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  Thank you for searching before asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your valve has slipped partially inside the hole in the rim where it exits. Normally it's on average about 1-1/2" outside the hole. You'll need to inspect the valve body to see if it's cut. You can't put a pump on it because the main body of the valve is stuck. First fix the valve body position, then inspect... Here's how to fix:

1. Deflate the tire about 90%.
2. Grip the tire where it meets the rim and pinch it together with your fingers. Do this for the circumference of the wheel. You want the bead of the tire the part closest to the rim to release completely.
3. Now grab the tire in one hand and the spokes in a another, hands about a foot apart.
4. Gently pull your hands together in opposite directions. The goal here is to get the flat tire to slide on the rim, straightening the valve. You don't need much about 1/2" to and 1".
5. Use your fingers to jiggle the valve back and forth to get it to pull fully out from the rim hole. Optionally use pliers but take care not to crush the valve cap threads. If it helps put a valve cap on to pull up and out.
6. **Here's your answer -->** With the valve position fixed you can now visually inspect the valve. If you see cuts on the side of the valve body you might have a valve flat that air will leak from.
7. Fill the tire back up taking care to keep the tire bead on and no inner tube bulging out from the rim.
8. If you saw cuts in step 6, jiggle the valve and make sure you don't hear air escaping. If you do the valve is damaged, replace inner tube. Optional: A bit of slightly soapy water works here too. Cover the valve body with soapy water. If you see bubbles leaking, that's bad, replace tube.

It's always good maintenance to keep your tires pumped up to pressure. Pay more attention to this if the bike has been sitting a bit. If you ride with low pressure the tire can slip on the rim giving the condition your valve is in. Good luck! :D

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! I managed to solve the issue. And yes I'm lazy with maintaining proper pressure in my tyres and I guess this caused the issue haha. Learnt my lesson!

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the issue is getting the pump head to lock on the valve.

Your tube has shifted and now the valve looks really short. You'll have to deflate the tube completely and move the tire around to wiggle it valve to a straight position. The pump should lock on to the valve without a problem once it sticks out far enough.

Comment: Another tip is to press your thumb down on the tire behind the valve to hold the valve in place while you put the pump on.

Comment: Adding talc/body powder to the tube before putting it in the tire may help prevent this from happening.  Right now they are possibly a bit stuck together.

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer too! Worked out eventually thanks!